# C# code generation

Tags: c#

i'm about to make a graduation project application
this application is gonna some way receive a description for a situation , and then accordingly generate c# code

i want to know in what field i need to search or how to autogenerate C# code

Comment: I can't wait for you to finish.  "Computer, write boring code to talk to the database for me!"  "Working..."  "Working..."  "Done!"

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_programming

Comment: Try searching Stack Overflow using the title of your question.  There is a ton of material already archived here. If specific qs result, repost.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about the types of situations and descriptions it will deal with?

Comment: @Kirk Woll, you know - any explicit solution - whether it is in any formal language, control/dataflow-diagram, state transition table - conceptually could be turned into code.

Comment: I vote you just make the program take any input, and then write the contents of itself from a const, you can claim that while it didn't generate the code that follows the situation, it generated code that would generate it. Free beer tomorrow and all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Kathleen Dollard's book](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6(v=VS.85).aspx) on this if you can.  She has a [website](http://www.gendotnet.com/) for this topic as well.

You have three options essentially:

Brute-force - creating the code files yourself in a text file

[CodeDOM generation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6(v=VS.85).aspx) - MS's built in way of creating code.

XSLT - What Kathleen uses.

Answer (score 1):

T4 templates can help too -

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx

And you could also generate IL on the fly. ;)

Comment: +1 for T4, I use them a lot and once you know the syntax it is great for generating large amounts of code.

Answer (score 1):

### CodeDOM

I've done a wrapper around codedom. You only need to create your own C# script and specify the types being used.

**Example**

```
public interface IWorld
{
    string Hello(string value);
}

string code = @"namespace MyNamespace
{
  class Temp : IWorld
  {
      public string Hello(string value)
      {
          return "World " + value;
      }
  }
}";

Compiler compiler = new Compiler();
compiler.AddType(typeof(string));
compiler.Compile(code);
var obj = compiler.CreateInstance<IWorld>();
string result = obj.Hello("World!");
```

Note that it was a long time ago that I wrote it. The example might not work 100%. (The Compiler class do work, the example might use it incorrectly).

Compiler source code: http://fadd.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/65227#925984

### Reflection.Emit

You can also generate IL using Reflection.Emit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx

It's a bit harder but more flexible, since CodeDOM generates a new Assembly each type you compile code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a set of MatLab tools that generates C/C++ code from state-charts and data-flow diagrams:

[Real Time Workshop](http://www.mathworks.com/products/rtw/)

[Real-Time Workshop Embedded Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/rtwembedded/)

[Stateflow Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/sfcoder/)

You should dig into it.

What will be the "description of a solution" in your case?

Comment: actually i imagine it like that, 
you will be provided a tool to draw your form using a pen, some boxes,triangles,...etc
the application will take description for the drawn items from you

that is text box, that's a combo box and so on

and then generate C# code for a corresponding C# form simulates your drawing
briefly, draw your form and get it in C#
that looks mad, but i'm still investigating 
..thanks for interest